# How to modify serialized attributes of objects in Django?

Tags: django

I need to change the field `product` to `name` of my OrderItem objects because of how Google Enhanced Ecommerce requiers the data to be processed.

**Requiered Fields for Google Analytics Ecommerce:**

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#product-data

**Working example**

https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#purchases

As said before, my model has this field as `product` but Google needs it to be named `name` instead,

> is it possible to change it in the view? Or do I need to change it
>   somehow in HTML using Javascript?

**view**

```
def thanks_deposit_payment(request):
    order_number = Order.objects.latest('id').id

    total = Order.objects.latest('id').total

    costo_despacho = Order.objects.latest('id').shipping_cost

    order_items = OrderItem.objects.filter(order=Order.objects.latest('id'))


    order_items = serialize('json', order_items, fields=['id', 'sku', 'product', 'price', 'size', 'quantity'])


    response = render(request, 'thanks_deposit_payment.html', dict(order_number=order_number, total=total,
                                                               order_items=order_items, costo_despacho=costo_despacho))
    return response
```

**template:**

```
<script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        window.dataLayer.push({
            event: 'eec.purchase',
            ecommerce: {
                currencyCode: 'PEN',
                purchase: {
                    actionField: {
                        id: {{ order_number }},
                        affiliation: 'Stickers Gallito E-Commerce',
                        revenue: {{ total }},
                        shipping: {{ costo_despacho }},
                        coupon: ''
                    },
                    products: JSON.parse('{{ order_items | safe }}')
                },

            }
        });
    </script>
```

**models.py**

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    quantity = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, verbose_name= 'PEN Price')
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='files', blank=True, null=True)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, default='')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**UPDATE 1**

Thanks to ruddra answer I get 'product' change to 'name', but the dataLayer shows:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

products: JSON.parse('[{'sku': 'M1', 'quantity': '10', 'size': 'varios', 'price': '3.00', 'name': 'Sobre con muestras'}]')
```

It only happens If I change the view with what the suggestion from that answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible to change in view, you can do it like this:

```
order_items = serialize('json', order_items, fields=['id', 'product', 'price'])  # the fields needed for products

order_items_json = json.loads(order_items)
products_list = []
for item in order_items_json:
    product_dict = item.get('fields')
    product_dict['name'] = product_dict.pop('product')
    products_list.append(product_dict)

return render('template_name.html', dict(order_number=order_number, total=total, order_items=json.dumps(products_list), costo_despacho=costo_despacho))
```

Comment: Ty. may you add a second version of your answer showing how to send the context variable when I'm sending other variables to the template. I've modified my question, to show my complete view for this.

Comment: Updated my answer @OmarGonzales :)

Comment: I am not sure, but can you please try with `products: JSON.parse("{{ order_items | safe }}")`?

Comment: that is what I have, whay I show in UPDATE 1 is what I get in Chrome's console.

Comment: @OmarGonzales please see my updated answer. Basically i forgot about using json.dumps

Answer (score 2):

You can annotate the queryset so that the result has a `name` field

```
q = Q(order=Order.objects.latest('id'))
order_items = OrderItem.objects.filter(q).annotate(name=F('product'))
```

Then replace `product` with `name` in your serializer fields.

Edit: Thanks to the commenters for pointing out that this doesn't actually work because Django's `serialize` will only serialize attribute that are fields on the model. You'd have to write a custom serializer as well.

Comment: That is actually a very good idea. But it won't work with Django serializer. But this line should work `json.dumps(list(order_items.values('name', 'id')))`. Also, you might need to fix the brackets, else it might throw syntax errors.

Comment: @ruddra it would be great if you could explain why this won't work? Why it should be: `order_items = json.dumps(list(order_items.values('name', 'id')))`?

Comment: django serializer does not serailize anything but the fields of the model. So when using `values()`, it will generate a [Queryset Dictionary](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#values). Then use `list(...)` to convert it to a list and json.dumps to convert that list to a string so that it can be passed as context.